# Equivalent to Win32 'SetProp' in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, properties, window

In Win32 API we have 2 functions called 'SetProp' and 'GetProp' to set and get the property of a window identified by HWND

SetProp:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633568%28VS.85%29.aspx

I have 2 applications, one coded with Qt, the other coded with Win32 API. I need some kind of flag so the application in Win32 can recognise the application in Qt.

Are there any equivalent functions in Qt to set and get the properties for QMainWindow?

Comment: If you needed such a thing, probably you would add a `QHash` member to the class of your window...

Comment: Process interop through a window is a pretty miserable way of doing things.  Can't you just listen on a socket or named pipe?

Comment: i guess using socket o pipe is unneccessary; i just need a tiny flag for the app in Qt so the app in win32 knows the qt one is its friend

Comment: Why don't you just add fields to your class?!

Comment: uhm, which class? i'm trying to recognise the friendly app by the executable file name, however, this is not secure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use the HWND of the QMainWindow returned by [`QWidget::winId()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#winId) in use with the two Windows functions that you mentioned in your question.

Somewhat related... here are ways to access other properties that are associated with a HWND of a `QMainWindow`:

Most are covered by the Window Flags

[Window Flags Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html)

[`Qt::WindowFlags`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

[`QWidget::setWindowFlags()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop)

and Widget Attributes...

[`QWidget::setAttribute()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setAttribute)

[`Qt::WidgetAttribute`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd use Qt AND win32 API, this limits your target platform to windows only..

Comment: I gathered from the question that they wanted to find a Qt window from another win32 program that isn't necessarily running Qt libraries.  To be cross platform, both processes/programs should have the Qt Libraries and use a QLocalServer/QLocalSocket and communicate that way.

Answer (score 1):

This should yield your answer:

[About using an undocumented class in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260763/about-using-an-undocumented-class-in-qt)

(Using setProperty or the undocumented class if you like being risky).

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html#setProperty